# Facebook authentication without login button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have followed some Facebook API 3.0 tutorials, including the Login/Logout and the Publish To Feed examples. So the login works this way:

1. App opens, shows a fragment which displays a login button
2. User clicks login, the authentication is done via the referenced FacebookSDK library (com.facebook.widget.LoginActivity) and the provided code using sessions.
3. User is redirected to next screen

I don't want to make the user to login this way. I want them to use my app without any login/registration, then if they click on a facebook specific feature e.g. share a note on Facebook, then the app should ask them whether they let Facebook use their app or something, you know the usual stuff. Without this I get a nullpointer in the publishFeedDialog() function as session is null, because no login has been made.

So my question is, how can I ignore the SplashFragment with the Login button, so when the user clicks on a Facebook feature in my app, no new screen is displayed with a login button, but only the default Facebook authentication window that users are used to?

Comment: Did u find a solution ? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Me to, any news here @erdomester?

Comment: I think we made some workaround but I am not working on that project any more.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

@erdomester, @sromku

Facebook launch new sdk version 4.x where Session is deprecated,

There new concept of login as from facebook

> [LoginManager and AccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) - These new classes perform Facebook
>   Login

So, Now you can access Facebook authentication without login button as

*layout.xml*

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_fb_login"
            .../>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.d("Success", "Login");

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn_fb_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_login);

    btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
        }
    });

}
```

### Edit

If you don't add the following, it won't work (rightly pointed out by [@Daniel Zolnai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135885/facebook-authentication-without-login-button#comment48833948_30230718) in comment below):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the new sdk a few days ago and I have to say it's a relief that finally the Facebook guys created something that can be used. Everyone should update to the new sdk.

Comment: This works fine for me. If your callback does not get called, check if you got the following lines added:

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

Comment: can you add full code with Login, logout and Getting profile Information. i need that.

Comment: Thank you @Sufian. Now my answer is completed.

Comment: Be careful that you set `MainActivity.this` as attribute to `logInWithReadPermissions()`. Or `this` will mean `View.OnClickListener` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: Hello friends this anser is nice but can I used this for fragment not in activity then what change i do ?

Answer (score 9):

Something like this

```
private void performFacebookLogin()
{
    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "performFacebookLogin");
    final Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
    Session openActiveSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "call");
            if (session.isOpened() && !isFetching)
            {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "if (session.isOpened() && !isFetching)");
                isFetching = true;
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                Request getMe = Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                    {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted");
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "user != null");
                            org.json.JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                            String email = graphResponse.optString("email");
                            String id = graphResponse.optString("id");
                            String facebookName = user.getUsername();
                            if (email == null || email.length() < 0)
                            {
                                Logic.showAlert(
                                        ActivityLogin.this,
                                        "Facebook Login",
                                        "An email address is required for your account, we could not find an email associated with this Facebook account. Please associate a email with this account or login the oldskool way.");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                getMe.executeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!session.isOpened())
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "!session.isOpened()");
                else
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "isFetching");

            }
        }
    });
```

Actually exactly like that. It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I have my custom Button "Share on Facebook". When user click on it then it check the user log state. If user has logged then post the text on wall otherwise prompt to login. I want to add the publish_stream permission. Please help me for this. How you achieved this.

Comment: Can you explain how to to define isFetching please?

Comment: boolean isFetching = false;  declare it as a member variable, keep it false except while fetching.

Comment: This opens a progress bar with black background, how could I use my own progress bar?

Comment: Can you add full code of Login, logout and Getting profile Information. with latest Sdk Without FB Login Button , i tried some Examples but not workingproperly .or please Suggest me a working Example.  @WIllJBD

Comment: Session doesnt exist anymore... Facebook removed it from its sdk

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.facebook.*;
    import com.facebook.model.*;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                  }
                }
              }).executeAsync();
            }
          }
        });
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

    }
```

if you need to get authorizations after verify that session is open ,add this way:

```
List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();             
                 Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new         Session.NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("read_mailbox"));
                 session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

Comment: What is your `permissions` variable for? It doesn't seem to be used in the next statement.

Comment: @KonradMorawski a little late but it is used for the type of data you want from the facebook profile (like public_profile, user_friends, email)

Answer (score 2):

This simple library can help you: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook
Just add this library to your project and make the reference from this library to Facebook SDK 3.0.x and add reference from your app to this library.

Then you can login without the `LoginButton` and do simple actions like publish feeds, get profile/friends, send invite and more.

This is how the login look like:

```
OnLoginOutListener onLoginOutListener = new SimpleFacebook.OnLoginOutListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onFail()
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to login");
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking()
    {
        // show progress bar or something to the user while login is happening
        Log.i(TAG, "In progress");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogout()
    {
        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogin()
    {
        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
    }
};

// set login/logut listener
mSimpleFacebook.setLogInOutListener(onLoginOutListener);

// do the login action
mSimpleFacebook.login(MainActivity.this);
```

Then, in `onLogin()` callback method you can publish feed like this:

```
// build feed
Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
    .setMessage("Clone it out...")
    .setName("Simple Facebook for Android")
    .setCaption("Code less, do the same.")
    .setDescription("The Simple Facebook library project makes the life much easier by coding less code for being able to login, publish feeds and open graph stories, invite friends and more.")
    .setPicture("https://raw.github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/master/Refs/android_facebook_sdk_logo.png")
    .setLink("https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook")
    .build();

// publish the feed
mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed);
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: SimpleFacebook is deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

A Turnaroubd to access FB details withot using LoginButton is

1)Hide Your LoginButton UI

2)Add your Custom Button

```
Button signup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginButton.performClick();//Where loginButton is Facebook UI
            }
        });
```

But I suggest to use LoginManager

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the login dialog using the Node powered [facebook-proxy](https://github.com/redaxmedia/facebook-proxy) module. Create your own instance on Heroku using the one-click-deployment button.

What it basicly does:

1. Requests an `access_token` from Facebook
2. Opens a proxy server using `express-http-proxy`
3. Let's you request all endpoints of the API

Answer (score 0):

You can change put the Facebook button and change the visibility. For example :

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout_facebook"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_continue_facebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/continue_with_facebook" />

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/loginButton_facebook"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

After, in your code (in Kotlin here), you can call the onClick() method of the Facebook SDK when someone click on your Button :

```
 button_continue_facebook.setOnClickListener {
            binding.loginButton_facebook.callOnClick()
}
```