# Android: How to change color of progress bar circle into Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to change the basic color of the progress bar into Facebook login process. So I tried that but it doesn't work at all:

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="FacebookStyle" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/FacebookProgressBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FacebookProgressBarStyle">
    <item name="android:color">#DBA347</item>
</style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
    android:theme="@style/FacebookStyle"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Have you got some ideas guys?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the facebook login progress bar as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357310/android-how-to-hide-progress-circle-in-facebook-login). Then you use your custom progressbar to show the loading as shown [here](http://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples)