# Disable Loading Spinner on Android Using React Native FBSDK

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using the [React Native FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) to handle Facebook authentication within my React Native application. I would like to use my own loading spinner, however `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions()` seems to include a loading spinner already. Is there any way in which I can disable this?

Related questions seem to involve setting `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` on `activity` tags in the AndroidManifest. The React Native FBSDK got me to include:

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />`

inside the AndroidManifest. I don't believe it would make sense to attach an `android:theme` attribute to this tag (I have tried this irrespectively, and did not reach the desired outcome).

I have tried adding the following `activity` tag:

`<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookAcitivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" tools:replace="android:theme" />`

to my Android Manifest, in addition to adding the following attribute:

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

to my `manifest` tag. This results in the application crashing instantaneously, upon clicking the button which invokes `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions()`.

When I run `adb logcat`, the following error message is present in the stacktrace:

`AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity {com.<my-company-name>.<my-project-name>/com.facebook.FacebookActivity} did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing`

Changing the value which I pass into `android:theme` to `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` prevents my application from crashing. It also changes the styling of the loading icon, but does not hide it.

Comment: There should still be an `activity` tag with `android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"` in your `AndroidManifest`. Did you try adding that theme attribute you mentioned there? You wouldn't need it on all `activity` tags, just that one.

Comment: The `activity` tag is not present (I believe FBSDK handles this). I've tried adding this, but have encountered further problems. I've updated my question to specify what I have attempted.

Comment: Did you run `react-native install react-native-fbsdk` and `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`? I've used the RN FBSDK before and the tag is in my manifest. Maybe that's not how it works anymore

Comment: I did indeed. I followed the Installation instructions specified on the RN FBSDK GitHub page.

Comment: I've managed to isolate the problem to using `Theme.NoDisplay`, and have added additional detail to the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question evolved to the point that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357310/android-how-to-hide-progress-circle-in-facebook-login/31369066) became applicable.

That is, to disable Facebook's loading spinner when using react-native-fbsdk:

- Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the `manifest` tag in AndroidManifest.
- Add `<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookAcitivity" android:theme="@style/FullyTranslucent" tools:replace="android:theme" />` to the `application` node.
- Add the styles specified in the aforementioned answer to `/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`.

Comment: I'm using FBSDK 0.8.0, I added all and it doesn't work, the spinner dialog appear when I use LoginManager.