# Remove dark overlay from google services account selection on google signin

Tags: android, react-native, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm using [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) to signin users with google on my app.
When using google signin on Android, the google services account selection dialog has a dark overlay on the background. Is there any way I can customize it's style so that this overlay is transparent?

[image: /Users/rodrigovasconcelos/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-03-23 at 15.39.55.png]

Comment: No. That's a native module using Google's API to bring up that overlay. Looking at the documentation and source, there is nothing that appears exposed to control the styling. And that is assuming that the underlying library even allows for it. Do you know if the Google API allows for styling that background?

Comment: I couldn't find much information about it, thus I asked the question. I saw people with a similar problem related to a spinning overlay with the facebook signin solve this with custom styling, so I though it could be possible in this case as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357310/android-how-to-hide-progress-circle-in-facebook-login/31369066#31369066