# Flutter: How to hide the progress circle while login using flutter_facebook_login

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter

I am using the flutter_facebook_login package to login the app. This method shows a login progress bar everytime I login. I want to remove that progress bar and use my own progress indicator.
How can I do that?
I already have a working progress bar and have used it. All i want is to remove the progress indicator of flutter_facebook_plugin.

I used a method where i tweaked the AndroidManifest.xml file. but it didn't work.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" />
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/InvisibleProgress</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="InvisibleProgress">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: i have a working progress bar.. but i just want to remove the progress bar of the facebook login plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for Android is available here,
works fine for Flutter plugin also

[Android: How to hide progress circle in Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357310/android-how-to-hide-progress-circle-in-facebook-login)