# E-mail field is null when logging in Facebook via Android app. Is this because Facebook sdk has been deprecated?

Tags: android, facebook

1. code below shows:- fb login button click ,session created, retrieving details in onActivityResult().
2. user.asMap().get("email") is always null but can fetch name user id

   ```
   loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
               @Override
               public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                       Exception exception) {
                   onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
                   System.out.println("onclick");
               }
           };
       }
   });

   private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
           Exception exception) {

       // When Session is successfully opened (User logged-in)
       session1=session;
       if (state.isOpened()) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
           // make request to the /me API to get Graph user
           String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ = {"email","user_birthday"};
           email=PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ[0];
           List<String> PERMISSION_LIST=Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);
           session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(getParent()).setPermissions(PERMISSION_LIST).setCallback(callback));
           Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

               // callback after Graph API response with user
               // object

               @Override
               public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                       com.facebook.Response response) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   if(user!=null){
                   fbID=user.getId();
                   }
               }

           }).executeAsync();
       } else if (state.isClosed()) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
           //otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...");

       Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened())
       {
           // Request user data and show the results
             String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ = {"email","user_birthday"};
               email=PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ[0];
               final List<String> PERMISSION_LIST=Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);
               Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday");
               //session1.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(getParent()).setPermissions(PERMISSION_LIST).setCallback(callback));
           Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new GraphUserCallback()
           {

               @Override
               public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                       com.facebook.Response response) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   if (null != user)
                   {
                       // Display the parsed user info

                       System.out.println("UserID : " + user.getId()  +"   name  "+user.getName() );
                       //System.out.println(" email "+user.asMap().get("email").toString() );

                       System.out.println((String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email")+" EEEEEEEEEEE");
                       System.out.println("Birthday "+user.getBirthday() +" hhh "+user.getProperty("email"));
                       System.out.println(user.asMap().get("gender") +" KKKKKKKKK");

                       fbID=user.getId();
                   }

               }
           }).executeAsync();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: May be yes go and checkout the new Facebook API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the new SDK as it is easier to implement and use, but regarding your problem, Facebook won't send you the user email, unless you ask for it, something like this (I didn't test it as I don't have the old SDK anymore):

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new GraphUserCallback()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                com.facebook.Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (null != user)
            {
                // Display the parsed user info

                System.out.println("UserID : " + user.getId()  +"   name  "+user.getName() );
                //System.out.println(" email "+user.asMap().get("email").toString() );

                System.out.println((String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email")+" EEEEEEEEEEE");
                System.out.println("Birthday "+user.getBirthday() +" hhh "+user.getProperty("email"));
                System.out.println(user.asMap().get("gender") +" KKKKKKKKK");

                fbID=user.getId();
            }

        }
    });

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "id,email,<OTHER FIELDS YOU NEED>");
request.setParameters(bundle);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Great answer!..May I ask about a way to Log in/Log out from FB without using the custom button provided by FB sdk?..

Comment: Using the new SDK, you just had to use the `LoginManager` provided by Facebook (example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30230718/1333516). Using the old SDK (here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25371663/1333516).
One suggetion that I would make, is to add the LoginButton to your interface and make it hidden, then when you want to login/logout just call `.preformClick()` on the LoginButton, that way the SDK will handle all the login and logout logic for you

Comment: if user has hidden email from timeline ,I cant fetch it ;again email goes null.
Is it a mistake ?

Comment: Facebook only gives you access to the information the user has made public. If the user hid the email, then you'll have to explicitly ask the user for it

Comment: ok..but the problem is first time when a user logs in via FB  - value of (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email") is null..after attempting  3or 4 times it returns the value also..how this happens?

Comment: when you say "after attempting 3or 4 times", do you mean login attempts?
Have you tried migrating to the newer SDK, there may be a bug on the API you are using