# Facebook SDK doesn't support on AndroidX

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, androidx

I got this error on facebook SDK. I'm using `androidx` to my support library
[image]

heres my `gradle`
[image]

looking into the activity itself uses supportv4 libraries
[image]
whats the possible fix here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by adding this two lines in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Try this use latest `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.39.0'
```

**Update**

**AFAIK** the current SDK of facebook  does not support with **`AndroidX`**

You can check here

[Facebook SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

> **Facebook SDK for Android Changelog 4.x**

[4.39.0 - December 5, 2018](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x)

**Modified**

```
In-app purchase auto logging is turned on by default. Android auto-logged purchases can be verified with uploaded credentials. Lean More
```

**Fixed**

```
Various bug fixes
```

## UPDATE 2

i have reported a bug

- [latest com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0 is not supported with AndroidX](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/356227448493879/?disable_redirect=0)

here is the Latest Response from Facebook Team

Hi Nilesh,

Thanks for reaching out. I'm afraid the **current SDK doesn't support AndroidX.** Unfortunately I don't have a timeline on when support for the library will be released, but stay tuned to our developer channels for any announcements in the future.

Regards,
Marc

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. hopefully they will support the soonest

Comment: The latest change on this bug "Just resetting this report's status as closed by design." is rather disappointing.

Comment: @Nilesh I didn't get the below status for the bug you file on FB. It is resolved or still pending?

Hi Nilesh,

Just resetting this report's status as closed by design.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: @AbhijitKurane the bug report  status is closed by design

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks for the info. I was about to start my new project and I'm just confused to take the decision to follow the androidx or old support libraries (till 28 version number). Just wondering how could I follow the FB integration in case I start with androidx. Your suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: @AbhijitKurane, you can have both. Just enable android x and the jetifier in your build and all libraries you use based on support will be automatically changed for using androidx.

Comment: @Snicolas thanks for responding. Good to know that I'm following the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by using android button widget in layout, this can be bypassed by using the facebook login programmatically:

refer this thread for programmatically using facebook login:
[Facebook authentication without login button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135885/facebook-authentication-without-login-button)